# Get the end of the string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to separate lines of strings and so far i got to the point where i need to get the end of them. And that's where my problem is.

My regex looks like this:

```
//these work fine
$firstRegex = "/^\w{3}\s+\d\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/i";
$secondRegex = "/\w{1,}\s\w{4}\[\d{4}\]/i";
$thirdRegex = "/\w{1,}\(.*?\)/";
//this is the incorrect regex
$fourthRegex = "/(\w+\s+)+\(.*\)$/";
```

Here are some of the lines that i need this regex for:

> *Oct  6 15:39:01 linux_server CRON[5921]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)*
>
> *Oct  6 15:39:01 linux_server CRON[5921]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root*

They should be with either brackets or without them.
My result is:

> *Oct  6 15:39:01 linux_server CRON[5921] pam_unix(cron:session)*
>
> *Oct  6 15:39:01 linux_server CRON[5921] pam_unix(cron:session)*

Comment: What is the issue? Is it that the last regex must match whitespace separated words followed with an optional parenthesized part? Then try `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?:\s*\(.*\))?$`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/55xqvF/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will have to use positive look behind, I am trying to match all the characters that follow ):

```
(?<=\)\:).*
```

You can use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) to work with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(\w{3} \d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\w+) (\w{4}\[\d{4}\]): (\w+?\(.*?\)): ([\w ]+)(\(.*?\))?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y01nce/1)